# Will leakage of fecal matter eventually stop after anal gland removal?

Tags: dogs, health

My Shih Tzu had his anal glands removed 8 days ago. He scoots a little and when he does fecal matter tends to come out. Is this going to get better and eventually stop?

Comment: Did the surgeon prescribe some medications or supplements for your dog post surgery?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm going to assume that the vet/surgeon prescribed some stool softening treatments. This is pretty common for this surgery since the dog is obviously going to be extremely tender in the region and softened stools will make it easier for the dog to pass any feces.

So, if that is the essential source of the fecal matter based on the scooting during the healing phase, then the short answer is yes, it will pass. Keeping the stool softened to the point of easy passage is a fine line between soft and leaking a little. I have a similar issue with a cat that has megacolon and it's a delicate work that sometimes leads to nasty messes to cleanup around the house.